# How do you update a field in contacts based on a field in Account page?

Tags: workflow, formula-field

I would like to have the Agency field on the contact page automatically fill in based on the account selected as agency is a field on the account page.  How do I do this so the agency field is populated immediately after account is filled in  and other field are still being completed not after saving the record with the account?  Would a workflow rule or formula work better?

Comment: Fetching a field(agency) based on account field without saving the record is neither possible by formula nor by workflow on standard page layout. It will require a visual force edit page which overrides the edit button. You can use plain JS or visual force action function/action support to achieve this

Comment: @Dataman434 - May be time to revisit your requirement, what is the need to have the field populated while the user is filling out the form? Are there other ways to work around it? If not, as others have said custom VF is the only option if the requirement cannot be worked around.

Answer (score 1):

You can't fill the field prior to saving the record because workflow run while system tries to save the record. Same happen with formula, formula field calculate value record is saved and field contains any value.

So in that case visualforce page is the only option left for you. You can use that to override standard layout and fill the specific field prior to save.